# Reference to class in another project is nothing, but setting properties does not cause exception

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a VB.Net with 3 projects in it: 2 migrated vb6 projects (main app and splash screen) and a C# project.

I am trying to upgrade to framework 4.5 from 3.5, and am seeing something totally bizarre: when I try to instantiate the splash screen class, nothing happens.  The variable it is assigned to shows as null, when I set properties I don't get an exception, when I read properties the assignment does nothing.

I get security exceptions later in the code:

```
33459681: Attempt by security transparent method 'XXX.UpgradeSupport..cctor()' to access security critical method 'SecondProject.classname..ctor()' failed.

 Assembly 'XXX, Version=3.57.5653.27754, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.
```

I am sure these are related, but don't understand how -- I haven't seen anything describing this behavior.